# Changing element width on-the-fly depending of other elements widths

Tags: jquery, css, width, modernizr

Since I'm not good enough in scripting I can't find right syntax.

Please take a look at Following image. I need to set `div.dependable`'s `width` as `X + 16px`, **even while window resizing**.

[image: illustration]

I have pretty similar example, please see code of `http://demuri.lv`. Try to resize window there  — blue block will be always in the horizontal and vertical center. But I can't figure out the correct coding for that.

jQuery, Modernizr loaded.

Comment: could you add your markup and css

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Moor/eqkkZ/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have first to hook on the `resize` event of `window`, find out the [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) of your wrapper from the left side and then modify the `width` of your element accordingly, like so:

```
$(window).on('resize', function (){

    var leftOffset = $('#main-wrap').offset().left;
    $('.dependable').css('width', leftOffset + 16);

});
```

This will work as you asked, but I'd also suggest that you add the same statement in the first place so you get the correct width at [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){

    var leftOffset = $('#main-wrap').offset().left;
    $('.dependable').css('width', leftOffset + 16);

});
```

<kbd>[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/uyoqil/1)</kbd>

In order to stick with the principle of [**DRY code**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) you might want to wrap the code up in a function statement; that would be highly suggested. Perhaps like so:

```
function offsetPlusX(targetElement, x){

    var leftOffset = $('#main-wrap').offset().left;
    targetElement.css('width', leftOffset + x);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to tap into the window resize event and be sure to use in your doc.ready loop

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var x = ($(window).width() - $('div#mainwrap').width())/2;
        var targ_w = (x+16) + "px";
        $('div.dependable').css({'width': targ_w});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, this implies that X is the value of the window width - the #main-wrap width and then divide that by 2 to get the width of each side. You must make sure to call this function when the DOM is loaded and every time the window is resized.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    calcDependable();
});

$(window).resize(calcDependable);

function calcDependable(){
    var x = ($(window).width() - $("#main-wrap").width())/2;
    x = (x < 0 ) ? 0 : x; // make sure value is always 0 or above
    $(".dependable").width(x+16);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for math, I'll need it later